# How to dynamically add routes in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, acts-as-commentable

I'm using [acts_as_commentable](https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable) in a Rails app to allow commenting on different types of models.

I've got a polymorphic `CommentsController` ala the [Polymorphic Association Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?view=asciicast).

I'm trying to write specs for this controller; however, I'd like to use [acts_as_fu](https://github.com/nakajima/acts_as_fu) to define a generic `Commentable` class for the controller to use in the specs. This way its not tied to one of our concrete commentable models.

The problem is that when I try to test the controller actions I get routing errors because there are no routes for the `Commentable` class I created using acts_as_fu.

I need a way to draw the routes for this dynamically created model in a `before(:all)` (using RSpec by the way) for the specs.

Here's what my spec looks like so far:

```
describe CommentsController do
  before(:all) do
    # Using acts_as_fu to create generic Commentable class
    build_model :commentable do
      acts_as_commentable :comment
      belongs_to :user
      attr_accessible :user
    end

    # TODO - Initialize Commentable routes
  end
end
```

UPDATE: Found a 'hacky' solution. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing this though.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for [adding routes at runtime in Rails 3](http://experiments.openhood.com/rails/rails%203/2010/07/20/add-routes-at-runtime-rails-3/), albeit a hacky one:

```
describe CommentsController do
  before(:all) do
    # Using acts_as_fu to create generic Commentable class
    build_model :commentable do
      acts_as_commentable :comment
      belongs_to :user
      attr_accessible :user
    end

    # Hacky hacky
    begin
      _routes = Rails.application.routes
      _routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = true
      _routes.clear!
      Rails.application.routes_reloader.paths.each{ |path| load(path) }
      _routes.draw do
        # Initialize Commentable routes    
        resources :commentable do
          # Routes for comment management
          resources :comments
        end
      end
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) { _routes.finalize! }
    ensure
      _routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it looks like a rails magic :) but we use this feature in our projects  to add some hack route in Test Env.