# Dynamically add route to beginning of rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a testing helper I am working on I need to inject a route into the *beginning* of the routes.  To add it at the end is easy:

```
  test_routes = Proc.new do
    get "/#{route_root}/:id", to: "#{route_root}#test"
  end
  Rails.application.routes.eval_block(test_routes)
```

The problem is that often there are "catch all" routes at the end of the application routes list, so I need to inject this as the FIRST route.

I have been using the technique here: [How to dynamically add routes in Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706713/how-to-dynamically-add-routes-in-rails-3-2)

but its hacky, and after a gem update last night it broke (not sure why yet, but its breaking inside of the `routes.clear!`) so I am looking for a less hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create your own module like this:

```
 module DynamicRouter
    def self.routes router
        router.get "/#{route_root}/:id", to: "#{route_root}#test"
    end
 end
```

and in your routes.rb just call your function:

```
 # in routes.rb
 # first line
 DynamicRouter::routes(self)
```

That's how we do with some of our custom gems. You can also monkey patch the router, but it's more hacky.

Comment: the point is that this is going to eventually be a general purpose test gem, that others can use.  I don't want to have to add anything to the routes.rb file.  The test helpers will do that automagically when the test starts.  Make sense?